# Separate digits from integer (without string functions)

Tags: c#, math, .net-core

I have an integer with only two digits, let's say n = 52, i want to be able to separate these two digits, like 5 and 2.

#### Left Digit:

```
    int left = (n / 10);
```

This gives me left = 5 for n = 52.

#### Right Digit:

```
    int right = (int)(((n / 10f) - (n / 10)) * 10)
```

### Error

The left digit is always true, but the right digits are sometimes right and sometimes wrong, and here are the test cases:

```
 1. 29, 48 , 10 , 50 : Correct 
 2. 52 : Wrong, gives 5 , 1
 3. 99 : Wrong, gives 9 , 8
 4. 26 : Wrong, gives 2 , 5
```

Comment: `int right = n % 10;`.

Comment: You've got two choices: a) treat the number as a string, and extract a character at a time (my choice), or b) multiply by 10/take the remainder a digit at a time (your choice).  You should *not* do your division in floating point space (unless you're taking binary digits, or unless you're very, very careful).  You *should* take the remainder ("%" modulus operator)

Comment: Hm, if you always have 2 digits, why not right=n-10*left

Comment: `m` can be used instead of `f` to get you the right answer. But @tkausl's solution is better.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't want to treat the number as a string (prerequisite), my mistake was that i was doing division in floating point space, the modulus operator was the way to do it, thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int n = 52 ;
```

Solution 1 :

```
int left =int.Parse( n.toString().Substring(0,1)) ;
int right =int.Parse( n.toString().Substring(1,1)) ;
```

Solution 2 :

```
int left = n / 10 ; 
int right = n % 10 ;
```